# How to explode structs with pyspark explode()

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

How do I convert the following JSON into the relational rows that follow it? The part that I am stuck on is the fact that the pyspark `explode()` function throws an exception due to a type mismatch. I have not found a way to coerce the data into a suitable format so that I can create rows out of each object within the `source` key within the `sample_json` object.

JSON INPUT

```
sample_json = """
{
"dc_id": "dc-101",
"source": {
    "sensor-igauge": {
      "id": 10,
      "ip": "68.28.91.22",
      "description": "Sensor attached to the container ceilings",
      "temp":35,
      "c02_level": 1475,
      "geo": {"lat":38.00, "long":97.00}                        
    },
    "sensor-ipad": {
      "id": 13,
      "ip": "67.185.72.1",
      "description": "Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders",
      "temp": 34,
      "c02_level": 1370,
      "geo": {"lat":47.41, "long":-122.00}
    },
    "sensor-inest": {
      "id": 8,
      "ip": "208.109.163.218",
      "description": "Sensor attached to the factory ceilings",
      "temp": 40,
      "c02_level": 1346,
      "geo": {"lat":33.61, "long":-111.89}
    },
    "sensor-istick": {
      "id": 5,
      "ip": "204.116.105.67",
      "description": "Sensor embedded in exhaust pipes in the ceilings",
      "temp": 40,
      "c02_level": 1574,
      "geo": {"lat":35.93, "long":-85.46}
    }
  }
}"""
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
dc_id    source_name    id    description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dc-101   sensor-gauge   10    Sensor attached to the container ceilings
dc-101   sensor-ipad    13    Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders
dc-101   sensor-inest    8    Sensor attached to the factory ceilings
dc-101   sensor-istick   5    Sensor embedded in exhaust pipes in the ceilings
```

PYSPARK CODE

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_sample_data = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([sample_json]))
df_expanded = df_sample_data.withColumn("one_source",explode_outer(col("source")))
display(df_expanded)
```

ERROR

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`source`)' due to data type
> mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not
> struct....

I put together this [Databricks notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8095340654854957/340630270058184/3643016617037570/latest.html) to further demonstrate the challenge and clearly show the error. I will be able to use this notebook to test any recommendations provided herein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `explode` for structs but you can get the column names in the struct `source` (with `df.select("source.*").columns`) and using list comprehension you create an array of the fields you want from each nested struct, then explode to get the desired result :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.select(
    "dc_id",
    F.explode(
        F.array(*[
            F.struct(
                F.lit(s).alias("source_name"),
                F.col(f"source.{s}.id").alias("id"),
                F.col(f"source.{s}.description").alias("description")
            )
            for s in df.select("source.*").columns
        ])
    ).alias("sources")

).select("dc_id", "sources.*") 

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+------+-------------+---+------------------------------------------------+
#|dc_id |source_name  |id |description                                     |
#+------+-------------+---+------------------------------------------------+
#|dc-101|sensor-igauge|10 |Sensor attached to the container ceilings       |
#|dc-101|sensor-inest |8  |Sensor attached to the factory ceilings         |
#|dc-101|sensor-ipad  |13 |Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders        |
#|dc-101|sensor-istick|5  |Sensor embedded in exhaust pipes in the ceilings|
#+------+-------------+---+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: During testing I couldn't find a purpose for the `*` prefixing the struct (`F.array(*[`) so I removed it and it had no effect. Please specify if the `*` serves a purpose, or if it was perhaps a typo.

Comment: @BradHein, actually not a typo. it's to unpack the list as the function takes a variadic argument (`def array(*cols):`). If you use an IDE like Pycharm you should get a warning `Expected type 'Union[Column, str]', got List[Column] instead`. I always prefer adding it